# Negative constants and operator precedence

Tags: python

I've been programming in Python for years but something extremely trivial has surprised me:

```py
>>> -1 ** 2
-1
```

Of course, squaring any negative real number should produce a positive result. Probably Python's math is not completely broken. Let's look at how it parsed this expression:

```py
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('-1 ** 2').body[0])
Expr(
    value=UnaryOp(
        op=USub(),
        operand=BinOp(
            left=Num(n=1),
            op=Pow(),
            right=Num(n=2)
        )
     )
)
```

Ok, so it is treating it as if I had written `-(1 ** 2)`. But why is the `-` prefix to `1` being treated as a separate unary subtraction operator, instead of the sign of the constant?

Note that the expression `-1` is *not* parsed as the unary subtraction of the constant `1`, but just the constant `-1`:

```py
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('-1').body[0])
Expr(
    value=Num(n=-1)
)
```

The same goes for `-1 * 2`, even though it is syntactically nearly identical to the first expression.

```py
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('-1 * 2').body[0])
Expr(
    value=BinOp(
        left=Num(n=-1),
        op=Mult(),
        right=Num(n=2)
    )
)
```

---

This behavior turns out to be common to many languages including perl, PHP, and Ruby.

Comment: I think your third code block has a typo, should be `ast.parse('-1')`, yes?

Comment: Fixed, thanks @Blorgbeard.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: I would have been very surprised if `-1**2` did not evaluate to `-1`

Comment: surround the -1 in parenthesis `(-1) ** 2`

Comment: Python aside, this is also the commonly accepted operator precedence in mathematics.

Comment: @harold As the parse tree shows, the negative sign is sometimes not interpreted as an operator. I would not have expected it to be, anyway.

Comment: @RyanGovostes I suspect that's an optimization. Even though it's semantically an operator, when it sees that the operators around it have lower precedence, it treats it as a literal negative number.

Comment: Which version of Python is this? On 3.6.8 it works as expected (adding the `UnOp` of negation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It behaves just like the docs explain [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals):

> 2.4.4. Numeric literals
>
> [...] Note that numeric literals do not include a sign; a phrase like `-1` is actually an expression composed of the unary operator `-` and the literal `1`.

and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

> 6.5. The power operator
>
> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its
>   left; [...]

---

See also the precedence table from [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Here is the relevant part from that table:

```
Operator     |  Description
-------------|---------------------------------
*            |  Multiplication, ...
+x, -x, ~x   |  Positive, negative, bitwise NOT
**           |  Exponentiation
```

This explains why the parse tree is different between the `**` and `*` examples.

Comment: I'm not sure then why `-1` is not parsed as "the unary negation of the constant 1" in either of the other two expressions I included.

Comment: Here's an important part also: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals "Note that numeric literals do not include a sign; a phrase like `-1` is actually an expression composed of the unary operator `-` and the literal `1`."

Comment: @RyanGovostes the unary operator has precedence between multiplication and exponentiation, that is why your example works differently for `*` and for `**`  (see my updated answer). The Python language may not be perfect, but someone some time ago established its rules and at least in this aspect they stick to the rules they set for this language.

Comment: Right. I suppose that it is as @Barmar suggested, and there is constant folding happening with USub(Num) subtrees. (But then why not just fold the whole expression?)

Comment: [`ast_opt.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9932a22897ef9905161dac7476e6976370e13515/Python/ast_opt.c) contains the logic for how and when such optimizations are applied.